# Spider for House Price Website

Tags: python, object-oriented, parsing

hey guys how you all doing, 
I built a spider that crawls through a house price website and stores houses address and transactions on it, through a bunch of functions, and I was wondering if anyone could help me refactor it, possibly pointing me in the direction of an OOP spider, so it would be easier for me to make an auto updating one, as this one just strips the website, not update it.

Here is code:

```
import threading

if __name__ == "__main__":

    areas = pd.read_csv('postcodes.csv')
    areas = areas['0']
    result_list = split_list(flattened=areas, chunk_size=50)
    threads = []
    outer_count = 1

    for i in result_list:
        print('Started thread No. ' + str(outer_count))
        t = threading.Thread(target=final_function, args=(i,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
        outer_count += 1
```

above code gets links from csv file, and around twelve threads get to work using final_function()

```
def final_function(link_set):
    root = 'http://www.rightmove.co.uk'
    pages = []

    for link in link_set:

        try:
            links = forty_page_getter(link)
            pages.append(links)
            print('Done for:' + str(link))
        except:
            print('not possible for:' + str(link))
            pass
    flattened = [item for sublist in pages for item in sublist]
    print('flattening the sublists done')

    for page in flattened:

        try:
            page_stripper(link=(root+page))
        except:
            print('couldnt do it for')
            pass
```

Final function will, for each page, get the rest of the results pages and then go through them with the function page_stripper, which is where I take all of the information:

```
def page_stripper(link):

    '''this function strips all the information on houses and transactions,
    ready for entry into the database, now make a function for the database '''

    myopener = MyOpener()
    page = myopener.open(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    houses = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'soldDetails'})

    for house in houses:

        try:
            address = house.a.text

        except:
            address = house.find('div',{'class': 'soldAddress'}).text


        postcode_list = address.split()[-2:]
        postcode = postcode_list[0] + ' ' + postcode_list[1]

        table = house.find('table').find_all('tr')

        bedrooms = table[0].find('td', {'class': 'noBed'}).text

        if not bedrooms:
            bedrooms = '0'
        else:
            bedrooms = bedrooms[0]

        house_key = save_house_to_db(address=address, postcode=postcode, bedrooms=bedrooms)

        for row in table[::-1]:
            price = row.find('td', {'class': 'soldPrice'}).text
            date  = row.find('td', {'class': 'soldDate'}).text

            save_transactions_to_db(id = house_key, date= date, sale_price= price)
        print('saved %s to DB' %str(address))
```

so this should be it for the explanation. I am sure you guys have much better and more efficient ways of doing this, and I would love to know them.Any refactoring advice, especially for someone who wants to extend this to be auto updating?
Thank you for your help